# Synonym request: [android-4.2] -> [4.2-jelly-bean]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, retag-request

To match up with our OS version tagging scheme, please make [android-4.2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-4.2) a synonym of [4.2-jelly-bean](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4.2-jelly-bean).